# How to add space between two wells in bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="well col-md-3">A</div>
<div class="well col-md-9">The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.</div>
</div>
```

It appears the two are right next to each other. How do I add a little spacing between the two well's? The older version of bootstrap seemed to automatically work when I use span0 for the div containing "A" and span9 with the div containing the sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same issue I fixed it by adding a div in the middle of the other two

```
<div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
        <!-- center buffer div -->
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the gap smaller than the col-md-1? It looks a bit large, I would like it to be at least half or 3/4th smaller.

Answer (score 18):

You could put your `well` inside `col-*` containers..

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3"><div class="well">A</div></div>
  <div class="col-md-9"><div class="well">The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.</div></div>
</div>
```

Or you'd have to customize the `margin-left` CSS of the 2nd well.

Demo: http://bootply.com/86483

Comment: I like this approach: instead of making the col-* divs a well, put a well div inside the col-* div.

Comment: way better way of doing it

Answer (score 0):

**More Simpler solution:**

Add `well` inside `col-md-*` in a separate div:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3">
 <div class="well">A</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-9">
 <div class="well">The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.</div>
</div>
</div>
```